# python3 Auto-logout after certain hour has passed

Tags: time, python-3.x

I have server application written in python3. It stores date and time of logins and logouts in sqlite3 database. What I need it to do is to check if a certain hour has passed eg. 23:00 and then write to database logout time eg. 24:00:00 to those users that haven't loged out yet (because at 23:00 it's obvious that they forgot to logout)  . I don't really know how to code this.

Edit:OK I'll specify my question maybe I wrote it too general, I don't really want it to write somebody for me just a hint how to start. How is possible trigger function after certain hour has passed.

Comment: We can't really write your program for you (unless you pay us), so why don't you try first, and come back with a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Depends how this program is being run.  If it is only running when the user does something (such as a web app, which serves a request, then terminates), you might need to create another job which is run by say cron (in the unix world) which would fire off at 23:00 and see if there's anyone who's been logged on for 10+ hours but hasn't had recent activity.  If on the other hand the server program is constantly running, you could look into something like the threading.Timer class to run a method at a specified time.

Comment: Yes I solved it couple days ago by threading(and I forgot to write it here), thanks for the answer anyway.